# About integration on polar coordinates.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$\Omega$ is the region on $xy-plane$ enclosed by $r = 2sin2\theta$ and $rcos\theta+rsin\theta = 1$. I'm to find these region's area but I struggle a lot. My reasoning is as the following:

[image: graph]

Let $\theta_i$ denote our angle between green ray and x-axis. Considering different rays for different $\theta_i$ values. For example, for orange ray we have our limits are from $0$ to $\frac{1}{cos\theta+sin\theta}$ and for the green ray $0$ to $2sin2\theta$. Since our curve is symmetric, we can divide our curve into two sub-curves and we can just compute one half of the curve then multiply it by two. 
$$\iint_\Omega dA=2\int _0^{\theta_i}\:\int _0^{2sin2\theta }r\:dr\:d\theta \:+2\int _{\theta_i}^{\frac{\pi }{4}}\:\int _0^{\cfrac{1}{cos\theta +sin\theta }}r\:dr\:d\theta$$.

I cannot see the flaw of my procedure but when it comes to estimate, this integral gives me for the fixed $\theta_i\approx0.216$  0.37. It is too much since the whole triangle has the area of 0.5. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The incorrect curve is plotted on Desmos because the $\sin$ is missing a factor of $2$. Perhaps this will increase the estimated area for the triangle, otherwise your method is sound.

Comment: I cannot even believe that I did such a small mistake. Thanks for pointing out, now all has came together.